# Python - is there any sample open source project which used pjsip with python?

Tags: python, centos, fedora, archlinux, pjsip

I am trying pjsip with Python 2.7.3 in CentOS, Fedora, ArchLinux, Ubuntu to have 
- sip registration
- sip audio codec encode/decode
- media access microphone, speaker out
- networking stun, turn

Till now i have written this following code, it works to register sip, place call stay connected.

But problem is i cant capture microphone and listen audio in speaker which is failing. So i was searching for some stable working sample if there is any. Can anyone please advise?

```
import sys
import pjsua as pj

LOG_LEVEL=3
current_call = None

def log_cb(level, str, len):
    print str,


class MyAccountCallback(pj.AccountCallback):

    def __init__(self, account=None):
        pj.AccountCallback.__init__(self, account)

    # Notification on incoming call
    def on_incoming_call(self, call):
        global current_call 
        if current_call:
            call.answer(486, "Busy")
            return

        print "Incoming call from ", call.info().remote_uri
        print "Press 'a' to answer"

        current_call = call

        call_cb = MyCallCallback(current_call)
        current_call.set_callback(call_cb)

        current_call.answer(180)


# Callback to receive events from Call
class MyCallCallback(pj.CallCallback):

    def __init__(self, call=None):
        pj.CallCallback.__init__(self, call)

    # Notification when call state has changed
    def on_state(self):
        global current_call
        print "Call with", self.call.info().remote_uri,
        print "is", self.call.info().state_text,
        print "last code =", self.call.info().last_code, 
        print "(" + self.call.info().last_reason + ")"

        if self.call.info().state == pj.CallState.DISCONNECTED:
            current_call = None
            print 'Current call is', current_call

    # Notification when call's media state has changed.
    def on_media_state(self):
        if self.call.info().media_state == pj.MediaState.ACTIVE:
            # Connect the call to sound device
            call_slot = self.call.info().conf_slot
            pj.Lib.instance().conf_connect(call_slot, 0)
            pj.Lib.instance().conf_connect(0, call_slot)
            print "Media is now active"
        else:
            print "Media is inactive"

# Function to make call
def make_call(uri):
    try:
        print "Making call to", uri
        return acc.make_call(uri, cb=MyCallCallback())
    except pj.Error, e:
        print "Exception: " + str(e)
        return None


# Create library instance
lib = pj.Lib()

try:
    # Init library with default config and some customized
    # logging config.
    lib.init(log_cfg = pj.LogConfig(level=LOG_LEVEL, callback=log_cb))

    # Create UDP transport which listens to any available port
    transport = lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP, 
                                     pj.TransportConfig(0))
    print "\nListening on", transport.info().host, 
    print "port", transport.info().port, "\n"

    # Start the library
    lib.start()

    # when no sound card found
    lib.set_null_snd_dev()  # here is the problem i cant capture mic, speaker from local system

    # Create local account
    #acc = lib.create_account_for_transport(transport, cb=MyAccountCallback())
    acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig("192.168.1.12", "abc", "admin2013"))
    cb = MyAccountCallback(acc)
    acc.set_callback(cb)
    #cb.wait()
    print "\n"
    print "Registration complete, status=", acc.info().reg_status, \
          "(" + acc.info().reg_reason + ")"    

    # If argument is specified then make call to the URI
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        lck = lib.auto_lock()
        current_call = make_call(sys.argv[1])
        print 'Current call is', current_call
        del lck

    my_sip_uri = "sip:" + transport.info().host + \
                 ":" + str(transport.info().port)

    # Menu loop
    while True:
        print "My SIP URI is", my_sip_uri
        print "Menu:  m=make call, h=hangup call, a=answer call, q=quit"

        input = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip("\r\n")
        if input == "m":
            if current_call:
                print "Already have another call"
                continue
            print "Enter destination URI to call: ", 
            input = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip("\r\n")
            if input == "":
                continue
            lck = lib.auto_lock()
            current_call = make_call(input)
            del lck

        elif input == "h":
            if not current_call:
                print "There is no call"
                continue
            current_call.hangup()

        elif input == "a":
            if not current_call:
                print "There is no call"
                continue
            current_call.answer(200)

        elif input == "q":
            break

    # Shutdown the library
    transport = None
    acc.delete()
    acc = None
    lib.destroy()
    lib = None

except pj.Error, e:
    print "Exception: " + str(e)
    lib.destroy()
    lib = None
```

Comment: I hate to ask, but have you verified that you can play a wav file using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your audio problem is related to what I explained in: [C - how to resolve this error while using pjsip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20312927/1419134). With this, you should be able to properly establish calls.

On the other hand, about a project using `pjsip` with `python`, I can only recall [python-sipsimple](https://github.com/grengojbo/python-sipsimple), but I don't have much experience with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have this small unit test where i want to execute `pjmedia_aud_subsys_init(&cp.factory);` how do i do that from python?

Comment: 1) int main() function you will see that function was called, http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/auddemo.c so from C it works 2) but in python there is no similar method, is it a BUG? http://paste.ubuntu.com/6523782/

Comment: @YumYumYum This is not a bug, is only that, current python interface, seems to be designed to give "high level" access, this is, to pjsip User Agent(UA), while media resources are directly managed by this UA implementation through a media endpoint(this automatically done when you call `pjsua_init`). Do you really need a so "low level" access? If so, you can try to create a wrapper for pjmedia_aud_sybsys calls but this should not be an easy task (at least in time).

Comment: YES - you are correct. High level implementation is not working when we do this "alsa". So we need to do something like low level access. Any hints how i can get started on my own for to have pjmedia_aud_subsys_init calls?

Comment: @YumYumYum OK, I may be wrong but, I think, the reason for high level not working is that you built only `pjmedia` and not all the project, am I wrong? If this is it, you can run make clean && make at the root and, initially, it should work. (remember to also build python module again)

Comment: 1) i did with high level test pjmedia but with no luck 2) with C after your fix/patch everything works with C 3) after your fix i also rebuild the python modules as $ python setup.py install  (i hope it reinstalled the modules like you mentioned 4) i also did make clean and make, make install but with Python like i said the audio issue remain as it was before your fix

Comment: @YumYumYum Please, check my update to [C - how to resolve this error while using pjsip?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20312927/1419134). To summarize, the problem is that, if you don't define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO to 0, it enables both audio devices, this works fine with the way pjsua_app.c initializes but not with python module.

Comment: Thank you. Yes C works without any problem. Python implementation of PjSIP is still a BUG because when recompiled Python should do the same as C. Which is not the case right now with version 2.1 of there release. So i will take it as BUG for Python implementation (not C which is working).