# Cannot use PJSUA Python module with PulseAudio

Tags: python, c, pjsip, linux-mint, pulseaudio

I'm maintaining a python/QT application (Linux Mint) using pjsua module designed to handle multiple incoming SIP calls. It's an old version, 1.x.

I figured out this module isn't compatible with PA, installed with Linux Mint. Plus, this module seems to access directly sound devices (`"hw"` stuff). So it can only work if the device is available, and won't allow PA compatible softs like vlc to access the sound.

I tried to edit the C source of shared lib pjsua module (`_pjsua.o`). Sloppy hack, replacing `"hw"` occurences by `"pulse"`. Not succeeded.

I ask here cause the solution may imply editing sources. But I think of interfacing PulseAudio with dmix as a workaround before...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem, not programmatically, but by launching the python script with `padsp` (a PulseAudio OSS Wrapper). Honestly, i don't fully understand why it's working. [Sounds like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312927/c-how-to-resolve-this-error-while-using-pjsip) the installed version of pjsip works in OSS mode.

Maybe could I check this fact and try to recompile pjsip with Alsa mode. Anyway it works now this way.

EDIT : it's not a stable solution ; sometimes it didn't work. I gave up.